# Create similar polygon by known area

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

I have a polygon (from $3$ to $n$ vertices, no holes) with area $S_1$. How can I create similar polygon with known area $S_2$ $?$ Centers of these two polygons must be in one point.

Comment: Draw a square of sidelength $\sqrt{S_2}$ around your center. Obviously, this trivial answer is not what you are after, but it fits everything that is in your post. You will need to say something more about what conditions your second polygon must satisfy to get a useful answer.

Answer (score 0):

Notation:- $L_i$, a 1-D measurement of polygon #i could be (1) the length of one of its sides; or (2) the altitude, if applicable; or (3) distance between the h-th and k-th vertices; or (4) its perimeter or (5) distance of a side from its center …..

Then, $\dfrac {S_1}{S_2} = (\dfrac {L_1}{L_2})^2$